# TensorFlow SparseTensor Input gives Value Error for multi-dimensional input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a keras model which takes multi-dimensional input data. When I build a model, setting the input shape to anything with multiple dimensions  and sparse=True, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x000002D24207B400>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'>) to a Tensor.

Following [the sparse tensor guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/sparse_tensor#tfkeras), this works for me:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(4,), sparse=True)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(x, y)
```

But if I add in another dimension, I get the error (which occurs at the second line):

```
x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(4,2, ), sparse=True)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(x, y)
```

If I set `sparse=False` then the error goes away:

```
x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(4,2, ), sparse=False)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(x, y)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could be this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/50078

Comment: May be this is due to `Dense` layer expect 2D input with shape (batch_size, input_dim). For more information you can [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks TFer2, but I don't think that's the issue. The documentation for the Dense layer says it will accept N-Dimension inputs, and the layer works with `sparse=False` at that number of dimensions. It looks most like a bug with the sparse implementation to me.